# Web hoster: Database connection and/or headers don't work - no error message

Tags: php, mysql, web-hosting

I've spent some hours on finding a suitable free web hosting service for a project's website. It's nothing overly fancy and doesn't include much more than a MySQL database connection and a very simple login system. However, I have not been able to find a single hosting service that gets the site running properly (everything is working fine locally).

In particular, the login script doesn't work online (similar problem with two web hosting services, [Byethost](https://byet.host/) and [Web4Free.eu](http://www.web4free.eu/)

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();
include "db-connect.php";

if (isset($_GET['login'])) {
    $login = $_GET['login'];
    if ($login == 1 && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $mysqli = checkDataBaseConnection();
        $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT `user`.`password` FROM `user`, `alumni` WHERE `alumni`.`mail`='".$email."' AND `alumni`.`id`=`user`.`id`");
        $hash_raw = $query->fetch_array();
        if (!empty($hash_raw)) {
            $hash = $hash_raw[0];
            if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
                $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;
                header('Location: dash.php');
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

db-connect.php:

```
<?php
function checkDataBaseConnection() {
    // Defining all variables, etc.
    if(!isset($mysqli)) {
        $mysqli = new mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_name, $mysql_pw, $mysql_db);
        if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
        }

        if (!mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, "utf8")) {
            printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", mysqli_error($mysqli));
        }
    }
    return $mysqli;
}
?>
```

Despite having set the error_reporting to E_ALL, no error is displayed after submitting an e-mail adress that is saved within the database (no matter if the password is correct or not). In fact, *nothing* is displayed, only a literally empty page. If the e-mail adress is not in the database, everything works fine. Even more strangely, the database connection works perfectly in another (non-login).

Is there some obvious error I have overlooked or are these problems related to some PHP settings of the hosting service? If so, can you recommend another free hosting service that *is* supporting these features?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Other than the SQL query not returning any rows, I can't explain this. You did load the 'user' and 'alumni' data into the database, right?

Comment: Unrelated: SQL injection, please replace `$email = $_POST['email'];` with `$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);`.